# 'requiresSelection' proprety not working for object page action extension?

Tags: sap-fiori, cds

For different facets in object page in List Report, when I add any custom action and add property "requiresSelection" to true, action remains disabled.

---

Tried adding below code in manifest.json

```
"Sections": {                                    
  "to_PDL::com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.LineItem": {                                       
   "id": "to_PDL::com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.LineItem",
  "Actions": {                                   
    "TestAction_Deactivate": {                                               
        "id": "TestAction_Deactivate",                                               
        "text": "Deactivate",                                                
        "press": "onDeactivate",
        "requiresSelection" : true
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the official SAP docu it says for property :
“Property that indicates whether the action requires a selection of items (true) or not (false). The default value is true.”

This means, that first you have to select a row in the table. Then the action becomes enabled.
Does it work for you this way?